# Cannot unlock after screen lock, intermittently

Tags: lock-screen

Intermittently, after my display(s) have locked because of the configured Screen Lock - I cannot unlock.
I get a password prompt, and am able to enter the password but, after tapping Enter, the busy circle appears and remains indefinitely - until I reboot. Or, I can also SSH into the failing system from elsewhere, and reboot from the command line.

Ubuntu 20.04.4, Gnome 3.36.8

In the syslog below, I try to unlock at 22:04:40, and eventually reboot at 22:05:09.

Is there any clue in this syslog extract?

```
Mar 10 22:00:01 localhost CRON[59125]: (flymike) CMD (. ~/.profile; rsync -a redacted...
Mar 10 22:04:40 localhost dbus-daemon[1186]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.61' (uid=1000 pid=2420 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar 10 22:04:40 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Mar 10 22:04:40 localhost dbus-daemon[1186]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Mar 10 22:04:40 localhost systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost NetworkManager[1188]: <info>  [1646967884.3598] agent-manager: agent[67d50e6f556b69d3,:1.61/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=2420 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=2420 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Mar 10 22:04:44 localhost gnome-shell[2420]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.172' (uid=1000 pid=59433 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'tracker-store.service': Unit tracker-store.service is masked.
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost nautilus[59433]: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit tracker-store.service is masked.
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.172' (uid=1000 pid=59433 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'tracker-store.service': Unit tracker-store.service is masked.
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost org.freedesktop.FileManager1[59433]: Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2019.02.14
Mar 10 22:05:09 localhost dbus-daemon[2148]: [session uid=1000 pid=2148] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
```